# openpyxl - load the workbook and save , open saved file with error message

Tags: excel, openpyxl

Error Message while opening the file:

Excel found unreadable content in zz.xlsx. Do you want to recover the contents of the work book?If you trust the source of the workbook,click Yes.

If I say "Yes" got "Repairs to zz.xlxs" pop up shows.

Could any one please help me. What format of the excel could have caused this.
As i tried sample workbook without any formatting it work fine.

My code :

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
#open existing workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'xx.xlsx')
wb.save('zz.xlsx')
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First of all check if your file *.xlsx format is "Office Open XML" or "XML from Microsoft Excel 2007/2010/2013".
If this is the format it will work OK.

By default the file is not saved as a template, you can define it to try if this is causing the error.
[Openpyxl documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=template)

```
wb = load_workbook('document.xlsx')
wb.save('document_template.xltx', as_template=False)
```

Comment: I just ran into the problem. `as_template=` did not work. The error was due to the excel version. I re-saved as a new version and `WB_NAME.save()` no longer created a excel-repaired file.

Comment: What do you mean by "I re-saved it as a new version" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and validate the file created with the MS Office OpenXML Productivity Tool but only if it was created on a machine with lxml installed. Otherwise please submit a bug with the script you actually used to create a file.