# Error while opening the Excel file after using openpyxl in Macintosh

Tags: python, openpyxl

I received the following error as I tried to open the Excel file which I have saved using openpyxl:

> Excel could not open excel_test.xlsx because some content is unreadable. Do you want to open and repair this workbook?

Is there a way to tackle this issue without having to click the "repair" option? I have looked into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355778/openpyxl-load-the-workbook-and-save-open-saved-file-with-error-message) but it does not solve the problem.

The original content of the file looks like this:
[image]

and here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

path_excel = ""

workbook_test = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = path_excel)
worksheet_test = workbook_test["Sheet1"]

for row_, cellObj_ in enumerate(worksheet_test["D"], 1):
    if row_ == 1:
        cellObj_.value = "SUM"
    else:     
        cellObj_.value = "= $B${0} + $C${0}".format(row_)

workbook_test.save(filename = path_excel)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, your code works when I run it on my Mac https://i.imgur.com/K22h7ZB.png

Comment: If you think there is a bug with the library please submit a bug report together with sample code and files.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this error only appears when using python 2.7. It works totally fine when I used python 3.5.

Comment: I have this same problem using Python3.6 on my Mac. The problem does not appear on Windows.  @CharlieClark, how do I submit a bug?